# Spring mvc:resources multiple locations

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

Documentation says:

> The resource location from which to serve static content, specified at a Spring Resource pattern. Each location must point to a valid directory. Multiple locations may be specified as a comma-separated list, and the locations will be checked for a given resource in the order specified. For example, a value of "/, classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/" will allow resources to be served both from the web app root and from any JAR on the classpath that contains a /META-INF/public-web-resources/ directory, with resources in the web app root taking precedence.

I`m having resources placed outside of my application like this:

- common

  - css
  - js
- module1

  - css
  - js
- module2

  - ...

And I want module specific resources to be available at `localhost/%module_name%/resources/` and common resources to be available at `localhost/%module_name%/resources/common/`

In *web-context.xml* for module1 I have:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="${spring.view.resourcesDir}/"/>
```

When I set `spring.view.resourcesDir=file:///c://resources//module1` requests like
`localhost/module1/resources/css` are working fine.

But when I set

```
spring.view.resourcesDir=file:///c://resources//module1,file:///c://resources//
```

Everything breaks, both `localhost/module1/resources/css` and `localhost/module1/resources/common/css` returns **404** error.
Same thing happens if locations are not nested, and even if second locations is something complete different like `file:///d://`

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in your question

> root and from any JAR on the classpath that contains

It should be under your classpath. You get `404` error when its not under your classpath. What I don`t understand is why do you want to specify an absolute path? Not a good choice.

Comment: `file:///c://resources//module1` is working, so it can be an absolute path.

Comment: can you confirm if you `bin` or `classes` directory does not contain `resources` directory in the first scenario? And what do you see in the second scenario in `bin` or `classes` directory?

Comment: There is no `resources` directory in my war anywhere, in both scenarious and I don`t understand why this is important since I`m not loading resources from inside my war or classpath.